# FuelPHPでログイン状態のチェック

Tags: php, fuelphp

はじめまして。
FuelPHPを使用して会員サイトを制作しております。

FuelPHPにはコントローラーで
before()関数が使えるのですが、ここでログイン状態かのチェックを行いたいのですが、どのような書き方がありますか？

ログイン時、非ログイン時でも同一のURLを使用し、
ビューだけを切り替えたいということです。
例 : http://example.com/
（ログイン時 -> 会員マイページ、　非ログイン時 -> サイト説明ページ）

言葉がうまくまとまっておらず恐縮ですが、ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

こちらが参考になるのではないでしょうか。
before()を使ったチェックのサンプルも載っています。

[FuelPHP Authパッケージ – Simpleauthの使い方 | hrendoh's memo](http://blog.hrendoh.com/how-to-use-fuelphp-simpleauth/)